# Python file to list

Tags: python, file, list, python-3.3

So I have file:

```
Ben cat 15
John dog 17
Harry hamster 3
```

How to make 3 lists:

```
[Ben, John, Harry]
[cat, dog, hamster]
[15, 17, 3]
```

I have tried everything, but I haven't find a solution yet.

I am using Python 3.3.0

Comment: Could you show an example of what you have tried?

Comment: Also, are you trying to make 3 lists in separate variables or a list of lists?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I have tried to split and readlines and etc

Comment: @DavidRobinson 3 separate lists

Comment: @DavidRobinson lists = [i.strip().split() for i in open("file.txt").readlines()]

Comment: @JohnSmith Please post the actual code you tried when you tried *everything*, and please prefer editing your question instead of using the comments to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("file.txt") as inf:
    # divide into tab delimited lines
    split_lines = [l[:-1].split() for l in inf]
    # create 3 lists using zip
    lst1, lst2, lst3 = map(list, zip(*split_lines))
```

Comment: It gives error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: @JohnSmith: Not if your input file is what you put above. What are the actual contents of your file?

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
ll = [l.split() for l in open('file.txt')]
l1, l2, l3 = map(list, zip(*ll))
print(l1)
print(l2)
print(l3)
```

produces:

```
['Ben', 'John', 'Harry']
['cat', 'dog', 'hamster']
['15', '17', '3']
```

Comment: I'm not sure this matches the desired output of the OP.

Comment: OP specifically asked for three separate lists, not a list of lists.

Comment: The inability of OP to go from a list of three lists to three separate lists is tangential to the question *and* why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @Mike also, if you want to be pedantic about what OP asked for, he asked for two lists of barewords and one list of numbers. Unless there are objects named `Ben`, `John`, `Harry`, `cat`, `dog`, and `hamster` already in scope it's unlikely this is actually what he meant. I think @NPE's (and my) responses were reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsi-17382 ~ $ cat file
Ben cat 15
John dog 17
Harry hamster 3
gsi-17382 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> zip(*[l.split() for l in open('file')])
[('Ben', 'John', 'Harry'), ('cat', 'dog', 'hamster'), ('15', '17', '3')]
>>> names, animals, numbers = map(list, zip(*[l.split() for l in open('file')]))
>>> numbers = map(int, numbers)
>>> names
['Ben', 'John', 'Harry']
>>> animals
['cat', 'dog', 'hamster']
>>> numbers
[15, 17, 3]
```

Comment: Read the question again. This is not the result the user asked for.

Comment: @DavidRobinson it is now, so your comment is outdated.